# Robot Framework with Jenkins - ‘pybot’ is not recognized

Tags: python, jenkins, robotframework

I am running a simple robot framework test with Jenkins.
I have installed Robot Framework plugin and have set up “Directory of Robot output”.
In "Build" I chose Execute Windows Batch Command a entered the following:

```
pybot C:\Users\joao\.jenkins\workspace\github_integration\Suite.txt
```

The file Suite.txt is in that directory and if I run this in cmd it runs the test.
However, in Jenkins my job fails and gets the following error:

C:\Users\joao.jenkins\workspace\github_integration\Suite.txt

'pybot' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I restarted Jenkins service and it just started working.
Thanks anyway!